# Best approach to continually monitor EKS nodegroup status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am creating and deleting the same EKS nodegroup (on the same EKS cluster) again and again and when the [DescribeNodegroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeNodegroup.html) function returns "Resource not found" I need to send a message to a sqs queue.

So essentially I need a service which continually monitors a EKS nodegroup status every few minutes and invokes a sqs queue or api when there is a status change.

I could do this with some sort of long polling operation but I thought that AWS would have a service/workflow which would be a lot cleaner.

Any suggestions on the best approach would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a CloudWatch event pattern that filters the CloudTrail API calls and listens on the required event and then trigger a lambda for every pattern match.

And in lambda, you can have a script that checks the event state passed on from CloudTrail to the lambda and pass it on to SQS if the state is as you wanted.

Let me know if this is something you are looking for. Happy to walk you through the implementation if required.

Comment: thank you for this answer, I can see this would work however I still need something which calls DescribeNodeGroup regularly (like every 10 minutes) how would you suggest that I do that?

Comment: @anton-james Ah, if that is the case, use CloudWatch cron to schedule a lambda to run every 10 mins. And in the lambda code, you can have the script to check the status of the DescribeNodeGroup and depending on the output of the status, it can report to SQS queue.

Running a lambda every 10 mins and considering the size of the code required, the time required to run the script, the cost incurred will be negligible. Let me know if this is something that you were after :)

Comment: thankyou this is great and will work, but I'm wondering if there is some way to do an event trigger approach instead of a polling approach. Im wondering if theres someway to subscribe to a nodegroup state change so far I haven't found one

Comment: I added a linked question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69007085/subscribe-to-eks-nodegroup-status-changes

Comment: Hey @AntonJames if the nodeGroup state has changed, that is definitely going to be an API call to AWS and that is logged in CloudTrail. You can filter the event source to be from eks.amazonaws.com or something like that. Because the state itself is changed by the parent resources eks or something.

And that API call is an event in CloudTrail which can be caught by CW patterns as I have mentioned in the answer above. That is the closest I can think of to get automatically alerted when the nodeGroup state changes.