# Subscribe to EKS nodegroup status changes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

Upon a nodegroup status change or a nodegroup suddenly not existing I need to execute some code.

I could implement this functionality by continually calling [DescribeNodegroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeNodegroup.html) like a long polling request.

However I'm wondering if through AWS it is possible to subscribe to node group (or other events?) status changes.

This would be a much more clean approach.